# How to add a circle to simple matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a plot of some data (simple 2-d line) and I would like to add circles around some more interesting spots on it. Surprisingly matlab seems to have no simple way to create a physically round circles. I looked on the internet and most answers i found was to either use `rectangle('Curvature',[1 1])` or `pts = linspace(0,2*pi, 100); plot(sin(pts), cos(pts));` and **fixing the aspect ration of a plot to 1**. In my case axes have scales that differ by several orders of magnitude so fixing the aspect ration is no option.

I was trying different ways to get the right x/y scale factor but it still seems I'm missing something. My current attempt is:

```
function hc = circle(x, y, xr)

gca_ylim = get(gca, 'ylim');
gca_xlim = get(gca, 'xlim');
gca_pos = get(gca, 'Position');
gcf_pos = get(gcf, 'Position');

gcf_ar = get(gca, 'DataAspectRatio');

%mod = gca_pos(4)/gca_pos(3) *abs(gca_ylim(2)-gca_ylim(1))/abs(gca_xlim(2)-gca_xlim(1))*gcf_pos(3)/gcf_pos(4);
mod = gca_pos(4)/gca_pos(3)*gcf_ar(2)/gcf_ar(1)*gcf_pos(3)/gcf_pos(4);
yr = xr*mod;
rectangle('Position',[x-xr,y-yr,xr*2,xr*mod*2], 'Curvature',[1,1]);
end
```

The circles that i got that way are still a bit elongated and I have no idea why. If there is any simple method to get circles in a plot - please share.

PS I know that if I resize plot or add some more stuff to it and change scaling the circles will re-scale with the entire plot. This is not a problem in my case - Figure gets printed out without manual manipulation (no window resizing) and I can add them as the last objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
>> h = plot(rand(1,5),rand(1,5),'o');
>> set(h, 'MarkerSize', 100);
```

[image]

Comment: Also interesting, and it seems like less trickery than scatter plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want scale invariant circles, you could use `scatter` command. You can also set the size smaller or larger.

> scatter(X,Y,S) draws each circle with the size specified by S. To plot
>   each circle with equal size, specify S as a scalar. To plot each
>   circle with a specific size, specify S as a vector with length equal
>   to the length of X and Y.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

Comment: As usual with matlab, you do stuff with trickery rather than designed solution. Still, it looks like it will work, thanks.